# Define a structure that contains a data array and some pointers to the same data array areas

Tags: c, pointers, struct, initialization, typedef

I want to define a structure that contains a data array and some pointers to the same data array. So I defined the structure and then I initialize the pointer like this:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char data[MAX_PACKET_DATA];
    unsigned char* sector1;
    unsigned char* sector2;
    unsigned char* sector3;
} Packet;

[...]

NGSCTransmittingDataPacket packet

[...]

packet->sector1 = packet.data + SECTOR1_OFFSET;
packet->sector2 = packet.data + SECTOR2_OFFSET;
packet->sector2 = packet.data + SECTOR3_OFFSET;
```

Can I initialize the pointer directly inside the typedef struct definition? If I write

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char data[MAX_PACKET_DATA];
    unsigned char* sector1 = data + SECTOR1_OFFSET;
    unsigned char* sector2 = data + SECTOR2_OFFSET;
    unsigned char* sector3 = data + SECTOR3_OFFSET;
} Packet;
```

the compiler gives me error.

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot do that, C won't allow it. But in your example you could do that equivalent:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char data[SECTOR1_OFFSET];
    unsigned char sector1[SECTOR2_OFFSET-SECTOR1_OFFSET];
    unsigned char sector2[SECTOR3_OFFSET-SECTOR2_OFFSET];
    unsigned char sector3[MAX_PACKET_DATA-SECTOR3_OFFSET];
} Packet;
```

There's no padding since all members are char arrays.

You normally cannot go further `SECTOR1_OFFSET-1` for an index of `data`, but there it would work (or create an union with a `MAX_PACKET_DATA`-length  array if you want to make it cleaner, because some compilers could complain if you're accessing `data` with a bigger index)

Example with an union of 2 anonymous structures:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SECTOR1_OFFSET 20
#define SECTOR2_OFFSET 50
#define SECTOR3_OFFSET 80
#define MAX_PACKET_DATA 100

    typedef union
   {
    struct
     {     
    unsigned char sector0[SECTOR1_OFFSET];
    unsigned char sector1[SECTOR2_OFFSET-SECTOR1_OFFSET];
    unsigned char sector2[SECTOR3_OFFSET-SECTOR2_OFFSET];
    unsigned char sector3[MAX_PACKET_DATA-SECTOR3_OFFSET];
   };
    struct
     {
       unsigned char data[MAX_PACKET_DATA];
     };
   } Packet;

int main()
{
   Packet p;
   p.data[SECTOR3_OFFSET] = 'a';
   p.data[SECTOR3_OFFSET+1] = 'z';
   p.data[SECTOR3_OFFSET+2] = '\0';
   printf("sector 3 %s\n",p.sector3);

return 0;
}
```

result:

```
sector 3 az
```